# Winforms: how to open combobox properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox on the winforms. On Enter even I open it:

```
cbo.DroppedDown = true;
```

But if I do that the combo opens and closes immediately. What am I doing wrong?

The reason why I use this event is I need to open combo on Tab, when user click tab on the previous control, this combo opens properly. But if user clicks the combo it opens and closes. How to do that properly?

Thanks

Comment: Umm, you should really make an effort to accept more answers.  You will get more frequent and better answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tried it just like this:

```
private void comboBox1_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
      }
```

no changes to mouseup or timers. it behaved just as expected. Whether I selected the comboBox with a mouse click or tabbed into it the drop down list appeared and stayed open until I selected something.

I would look to see if there is something else pulling focus off the box.

Comment: `((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;`

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are having this problem is because the mouseup event occurs after the enter event and the default window procedure is closing the combobox.

In the enter you could check the mouse button status and if the button is down, do not open the combo. Then have another event handler for the mouseup event to open the combo.

Another option is to set a timer for a few milliseconds, and open the combo when it goes off.

Comment: Expanded the answer with possible better solution.

Comment: How could I check the mouse if EventArgs e doesn't have such field?

Answer (score 3):

Knowing this is a bit old, but I found that this works well. You can TAB into the combo box and it opens and if you click the arrow it doesn't close back up.

```
private void ComboBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
            ((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set DroppedDown = true in GotFocus event of the combobox. Otherwise, the dropdown list will show at wrong location.

```
void cbo_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbo = sender as ComboBox;
        cbo.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to focus it first before open the comboBox.

```
cbo.Focus();
cbo.DroppedDown = True
```

Hope it works for you.