# Open ComboBox DropDown programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to **directly** open the WindowsForms combobox programmatically? Have not found a method or property to do so. If not, what are possible solutions that do not involve a lot of hacking.

Comment: [What about this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809596/winforms-how-to-open-combobox-properly)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can't tell why I did not find it myself.

Answer (score 64):

Use [ComboBox.DroppedDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown.aspx) Property:

```
comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
```

Comment: I've found that you also need to set the focus to the combo box prior to displaying its dropdown. Otherwise it won't work properly.