# How to make combo box auto expand on mouse hover and close when the mouse leaves combo box in c#?

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer, mousehover

I have a windows form. In that windows form i have a combo box. I have predefined items in the combo box as **Add, Remove and Delete.** **I want to make the combo box auto expand on mouse hover.** How can I do that? I noticed that auto expand code should be given in the mouse hover event of combo box. like this

```
     private void comboBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but I don't know how to expand the combo box. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Ok I got it done the expanding part

```
    private void comboBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;

    }
```

but I want to close the combo box when I leave the mouse pointer from the combo box.. How to do that?

Comment: Look at my comment below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DroppedDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown(v=vs.110).aspx) Property and make it true,

```
 private void comboBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var box = sender as ComboBox ;
       box.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Comment: This will only work for the small arrow part of the combobox. using mouseenter, possibly with a timer would correct that. the true challenge will be to close it on leaving.. there is a post somewhere, that actually works, but it's rather hard core, as far as i remember.. BTW: for a single cb the casting is unnecessary..

Comment: @TaW yeah it doesn't close when removing the mouse.

Comment: @Sajeetharan it works, but the problem is it doesn't close as the mouse leave.

Comment: In the MouseMove: `if (!comboBox1.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location)) comboBox1.Capture = false; else if (comboBox1.Capture == false) {
 comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
  timer1.Interval = 1000; timer1.Start();   }` and in a Timer: `Point MP = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X, Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y);   Size DDS = new Size(comboBox1.DropDownWidth, comboBox1.DropDownHeight);  Rectangle DDR = new Rectangle(new Point(comboBox1.Left, comboBox1.Top + comboBox1.Height), DDS);   if (!DDR.Contains(MP)) { comboBox1.DroppedDown = false; timer1.Stop(); }`

Comment: Cool, I have pulled it from an old testcase. You may want to play with the timer intervall - I just saw that I had 100ms originaly..

Answer (score 0):

comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;

This has already been answered here [Open ComboBox DropDown programmatically [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191347/open-combobox-dropdown-programmatically)

which was actually a duplicate of [Winforms: how to open combobox properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809596/winforms-how-to-open-combobox-properly)