# ComboBox Dropdown when Mouse Enter WPF

Tags: wpf

How to make `ComboBox` drop down automatically,

when Mouse Enter in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, setting `IsDropDownOpen` property can do it

xaml:

```
    <ComboBox Name="cb" IsEditable="True"  MouseEnter="Cb_OnMouseEnter"/>
```

code:

```
  private void Cb_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      cb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
  }
```

-

In winform there is `DroppedDown` property to set.

```
cbo.DroppedDown = true;
```

by this link:

[How to make combo box auto expand on mouse hover and close when the mouse leaves combo box in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547274/how-to-make-combo-box-auto-expand-on-mouse-hover-and-close-when-the-mouse-leaves)

Comment: instead of duplicating the question, why dont you upvote the other link answer

Comment: the different is, the link is about winform,  my question is about wpf, I just edit the answer move wpf part former