# Open ComboBox when I move focus to it

Tags: c#, combobox

Ok so... I have a basic winform with 2 fields, first field is a TextBox and the second field is a ComboBox. The combobox has Items already loaded into it.

When a user inputs text into the Textbox and clicks  the focus moves from the Textbox to the combobox.

When the combobox gains focus, I need it to display the options in the combobox. Currently all that happens is that the combobox looks like a textbox like control that has focus.

What do I call to open the options for the ComboBox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809596/winforms-how-to-open-combobox-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ComboBox.DroppedDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown.aspx) Property in your comboBox.GotFocus event:

```
comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
```

Comment: Thanks... so simple! feel like I was searching forever for this. Shot!